# Разница между frame.size.width и frame.width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Всем привет объясните пожалуйста разницу между:
`frame.size.width` и `frame.width` когда и что использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371076/difference-between-uiview-frame-size-width-vs-frame-width

`frame.width` только get параметр ему нельзя присвоить значение
`frame.size.width = 5`  а ему можно присваивать значение.

Comment: Спасибо получаеться лучше использовать лучше frame.width если я не хочу меня значения?

Comment: @ЮраПетров да. Всегда пожалуйста.